# change bootstrap active tab without having nav

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i have a modal and in my modal there are 3 tabs but the user cannot see any nav-tabs to change the tabs there are some buttons in the modal-body to switch between specific tabs.
i want when this modal opens every time i see a specific tab(the first one always). what happens now is that i see the last closed tab.

here is a sample of my code

```
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModalID"">open modal</button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="theModalID" role="dialog">
        <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <!-- tab 1 -->
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <!-- tab 2 -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <!-- tab 3 -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

i want on modal show every time see tab 1 as the active tab.
i mention again there is no nav-tabs to switch between tabs.
tnx

Comment: Please add the html for element that show modal.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your problem and please post more  relevant HTML  Code. Right now what I can guess is you have not added the class `active` for the tab-content

Comment: @hsbr13 i already answered, see my answer below and ask me if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger buttons on the opening of the tabs that will show the first tab button on modal opening. **show.bs.modal** event is the event of the bootstrap that fires before the modal opens. **DEMO** below:

```js
  $("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
              $('#tab2-btn').trigger("click");
            });
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                            <!-- tab 1 -->
                            tab 1 text
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <!-- tab 2 -->
                            tab 2 text
                            <button id="tab2-btn"  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <!-- tab 3 -->
                            tab 3 text
                            <button id="tab1-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Am glad and remember bootstrap has all these events when you work with tabs, modal, tooltip etc. apply them like i have applied it using shown.bs.modal event.

Comment: alright tnx again ... would you take a look at this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616276/bootstrap-loading-wrong-grid-on-mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can add function onclick for your modal trigger to show the first tab every time

As you didn't provide the html code for modal trigger element so i supposed any element

```js
showTabOne = function(){
 $('button[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="showTabOne()">Open Modal</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display:none">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <!-- tab 1 -->
                        tab 1 text
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</button>
                    </div>                                                                  
                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <!-- tab 2 -->
                        tab 2 text
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <!-- tab 3 -->
                        tab 3 text
                        <button id="tab1-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

or another option is to trigger click on the button that open tab1
so js in this case will be

```
showTabOne = function(){
        $('#tab1-btn').click();
}
```

jsfiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cfw86ao1/) for both options (second one is commented)